# getting RangeError [ERR_HTTP_INVALID_STATUS_CODE]: Invalid status code: 11000 Node Js after Insert Many to MongoDB

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, npm-start

i keep getting this error after pushing data to mongodb, eventhough the vaLue inserted into database but it keeps sending me this error

```
node:internal/errors:477
    ErrorCaptureStackTrace(err);
    ^

RangeError [ERR_HTTP_INVALID_STATUS_CODE]: Invalid status code: 11000
    at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:387:5)
    at ServerResponse.writeHead (node:_http_server:297:11)
    at ServerResponse._implicitHeader (node:_http_server:288:8)
    at write_ (node:_http_outgoing:826:9)
    at ServerResponse.end (node:_http_outgoing:934:5)
    at ServerResponse.send (C:\Users\USER\Desktop\form-back-end\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:221:10)
    at ServerResponse.json (C:\Users\USER\Desktop\form-back-end\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:267:15)
    at registerBulks (file:///C:/Users/USER/Desktop/form-back-end/controllers/AuthController.js:206:35)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5) {
  code: 'ERR_HTTP_INVALID_STATUS_CODE'
}
```

below is my code when i try to push the data into database using query insertMany

```
async registerBulks(req, res) {
    try {
      let salt = await bcrypt.genSalt(10);
      let hash = await bcrypt.hash("nabatiUser", salt);

      // console.log("data", req.body.data);
      const datas = req.body.data;
      const newUser = datas.map((obj) => ({
        ...obj,
        password: hash,
        role: "user",
      }));

      console.log(newUser);
      const user = await User.insertMany(newUser);

      if (!user) {
        throw { code: 500, message: "USER_REGISTER_FAILED" };
      }
      return res.status(200).json({
        status: true,
        message: "USER_REGISTER_SUCCESS",
      });
    } catch (err) {
      if (!err.code) {
        err.code = 500;
      }
      return res.status(err.code).json({
        status: false,
        message: err.message,
      });
    }
  }
```

i really don't see something wrong here... but it keeps getting error everytime i insert the data

Comment: is there a way to fix it? i dont see any duplicate on my data

Comment: In mongodb code 11000 means your passing duplicate values that are already exists in the database, try to send unique values and make sure to check the schema fields which has unique to true property. Remove this and set status code to 500 directly
`if (!user) {  throw { code: 500, message: "USER_REGISTER_FAILED" }; }`